# alias of class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

Consider an alias template like the `A` in the code below. Now let `B` be an alias template of `A`.

In the code below these class templates are used as template arguments for a struct `C` which is only specialized for one typename (`A`). `clang -std=c++11` exists with `error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'C<B>'` indicating that another specialization for `B` is needed.

```
template<int N>
using A = int;

template<int N>
using B = A<N>;

template<template<int> class I>
struct C;

template<>
struct C<A> {};

int main() {
  C<A> c;
  C<B> d; // clang error: implicit instantiation
}
```

Why (if even) is it that - despite not allowing specializations of aliases - `A` and `B` are treated as different class templates? Is there a workaround allowing me to rename a lengthy template without incurring this problem?

Comment: I think that has changed in standard, and now `A` and `B` are really identical (but anyway behavior changes between compiler/version).

Comment: @Jarod42 it was the other way around. This will most probably never change. See below referenced CWG 1286 and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1244

Comment: gcc accepts it btw [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fb301a524ea38bc)

Comment: Great question. Since it appears this will not change, the part of the question regarding a workaround seems even more important now. (Best I have is a macro, but nobody wants that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [CWG issue #1286](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286), which deals with this example:

> ```
> template<template<class> class TT> struct X { };
> template<class> struct Y { };
> template<class T> using Z = Y<T>;
> X<Y> y;
> X<Z> z;
> ```

questioning whether or not `y` and `z` have the same type.

Basically, according to the Standard, clang is correct in rejecting the code. All [temp.alias] tells us is:

> When a *template-id* refers to the **specialization of an alias template**, it is equivalent to the associated type
>   obtained by substitution of its *template-argument*s for the *template-parameter*s in the *type-id* of the alias
>   template.

So while `A<X>` is equivalent to `B<X>` (for all `X`!), there is no wording that `A` is equivalent to `B`. But on some level that doesn't really make any sense since `B` and `A` *should be* equivalent. There is a proposed resolution that would make them so, but it has not yet been approved.